# Problem in displaying the image in Textiew Using the Html.ImageGetter

Tags: android

I want to display image in TextView with text, I had used Html.ImageGetter but image was not displayed this is my code, please tell me what is wrong in this code

```
public class MyTest extends Activity {

TextView t=null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textcode);

    t.setText(Html.fromHtml("Hi", imgGetter, null));

}

private ImageGetter imgGetter = new ImageGetter() {

    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            Drawable drawable = null;
            try {

                    drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
                    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable
                                    .getIntrinsicHeight());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("Exception thrown",e.getMessage());
            } 
            return drawable;
    }
};

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImageGetter` is used for `<img>` tag parsing. So you have to have an `<img>` tag in your HTML code. For example,

```
t.setText(Html.fromHtml("Hi <img src='some_image'>", imgGetter, null));
```

But you'd better make the `ImageGetter` subclass return an image depending on the `source` argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display image to text view you can use the following code

```
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.smiley );
img.setBounds( 0, 0, 60, 60 );
txtVw.setCompoundDrawables( img, null, null, null );
```

### Otherwise

If you want to display text along with image you can use `WebView` instead of `TextView` and pass the data to webview

```
webview.loadData("html text", "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Thanks
Deepak